# InternalError: Invalid variable reference. [Op:ResourceApplyAdam] on TensorFlow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am currently working on EagerExecution with tensorflow 1.7.0.

I get this error when I am working on GPU : 
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Invalid variable reference. [Op:ResourceApplyAdam]

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to isolate the error so I can't give a snippet which could explain that.

The error doesn't occur when I am working on CPU. My code was working fine on GPU until a recent update. I don't think it is machine related because it occurs on different machines.

I wasn't able to find something relevant so if you have any hints on what can cause this error, please let me know.

Complete tracking :

```
2018-07-19 17:52:32.393711: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1273] OP_REQUIRES failed at training_ops.cc:2507 : Internal: Invalid variable reference.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "debugging_jules_usage.py", line 391, in <module>
    mainLoop()
  File "debugging_jules_usage.py", line 370, in mainLoop
    raise e
  File "debugging_jules_usage.py", line 330, in mainLoop
    Kn.fit(train)
  File "/home/jbayet/xai-link-prediction/xai_lp/temporal/models_temporal.py", line 707, in fit
    self._train_one_batch(X_bis, i)
  File "/home/jbayet/xai-link-prediction/xai_lp/temporal/models_temporal.py", line 639, in _train_one_batch
    self.optimizer.minimize(batch_model_loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
  File "/home/jbayet/miniconda3/envs/xai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 409, in minimize
    name=name)
  File "/home/jbayet/miniconda3/envs/xai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 564, in apply_gradients
    update_ops.append(processor.update_op(self, grad))
  File "/home/jbayet/miniconda3/envs/xai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 161, in update_op
    update_op = optimizer._resource_apply_dense(g, self._v)
  File "/home/jbayet/miniconda3/envs/xai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/adam.py", line 166, in _resource_apply_dense
    grad, use_locking=self._use_locking)
  File "/home/jbayet/miniconda3/envs/xai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/gen_training_ops.py", line 1105, in resource_apply_adam
    _six.raise_from(_core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Invalid variable reference. [Op:ResourceApplyAdam]
```